# Finding the index of datetime Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime, indexing

How can I write a code that shows me the indexes of `Newdate` within `Setups`. I want to get  the index value for each of the date values, so for the first output;`'2017-12-22T03:31:00.000000000'` date value in `Newdate` comes 6th from the beginning from `Setups` the output will be `5`.How would I be able to get the `Expected Output`.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

Setups= np.array(['2017-09-15T07:11:00.000000000','2017-09-15T11:25:00.000000000',
 '2017-09-15T12:11:00.000000000', '2017-12-22T03:14:00.000000000',
 '2017-12-22T03:26:00.000000000', '2017-12-22T03:31:00.000000000',
 '2017-12-22T03:56:00.000000000'],dtype="datetime64[ns]")

Newdate =  np.array(['2017-09-15T07:11:00.000000000', '2017-12-22T03:31:00.000000000','2017-09-15T11:25:00.000000000', '2017-12-22T03:56:00.000000000'],dtype="datetime64[ns]")
```

Expected Output:

```
[0, 5, 1, 6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert setups to a list and use `index()`:

```
setups_list = list(Setups)
indices = [setups_list.index(n) for n in Newdate]
print(indices)

# [0, 5, 1, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.isin` to get the truthfulness of the values i.e. either the values are common or not, then pass it to `numpy.where` which will give you the  indices of `True` values

```py
>>> np.where(np.isin(Setups, Newdate))
(array([0, 1, 5, 6], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: This returns the position of items present in the `Setups` but not in order they are given in `Newdate`. For example if you had recurring items in `Newdate` , this solution doesn't provide their indices

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, yeah that is True that it returns the position based on the values in `Setups` but not in `Newdate`